# Refer a CSS file in BundleConfig generate WebGrease.dll error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

When I put a specific CSS file called `glyphicons.css` in my BundleConfig occurs the following error

`An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WebGrease.dll but was not handled in user code`

and the file exist in my solution in the specific path, like all the anothers CSS files.

Someone has faced this problem yet ?

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/css/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/css/uploadfyBoot/style.css",
                "~/Content/css/uploadfyBoot/jquery.fileupload.css",
                "~/Content/css/tipografia.css",
                "~/Content/css/glyphicons.css"
                ));
```

If I remove the reference to glyphicons.css it works.

Comment: Is the file already minified? I came across an issue in MVC3 whereby I was bundling a minified version of jQuery

Comment: Its weird, because if I open an project as WebForms it works, but if the project is MVC 4, I got this error

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue . My project is done using MVC5. I tried updating the webGrease using NuGet package manager and reopened the solution and it worked .

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Visual studio 2013:
After adding those new bootstrap files into your content folder, Update BundleConfig.cs to reflect your changes. 
The following step is **important** if you are still getting that error. 
Its not uncommon that the files that you downloaded from bootswatch.com **mismatch** with your 2013 project. I fixed my error by updating by **Microsoft ASP.NET MVC** and **webGrease** using Manage NuGet Packages.
After you update these two, close and re-open your solution.

Comment: nice info, i updated my webgrease using manage nuget packages then rebuild solution, and done

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem.  My version of webgrease.dll was the latest so there was nothing to update.   A closer look at my BundleConfig file revealed the following.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/css/cssfile1.css",
            "~/Content/css/cssfile2.css",
            ));
```

While creating my css bundles I'd accidentally copy-pasted a script bundle code  block.  The following fixed it:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/css/cssfile1.css",
            "~/Content/css/cssfile2.css",
            ));
```

In short, I swapped "ScriptBundle" for "StyleBundle".  Works fine now.

Comment: what a weird error. could never spot this. tried clearing all temps restarted vs many times and finally seen your comment. What a helpful error message we get from .net

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh ha ha i've been called worse.  Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Type this In Nuget "Install-Package WebGrease"

Comment: top answer is the answer validates by asker then after the most voted answers. You can't put your answer as top position (who said that your answer is the best? Everyone thinks his answer is the best community says that your answer is the less good one)